# Count the number of initial conacts per day SQL

Tags: sql

This is from someone with a low level of SQL knowledge using MS Access

I have some data that looks like this in a table called T1:

```
Customer    ...........Visit  
c………….      01/01/2001  
b……………      01/01/2001  
b……………      01/01/2001  
a………..      01/01/2001  
b………..  02/01/2001  
a……..       02/01/2001  
d…………       02/01/2001  
e………..      03/01/2001  
d……….       03/01/2001  
c………..      03/01/2001
```

I've written some SQL to identify the first instance of a customer:

```
   SELECT Customer , MIN(Visit) as 'First Contact'  
     FROM T1   
     GROUP BY cust;
```

This produces a list of the first day customers contact us

```
Customer......  'First Contact'  
a…...............       01/01/2001  
b………    ....    01/01/2001  
c………......      01/01/2001  
d……..........       02/01/2001  
e……...……        03/01/2001
```

All fine and dandy but what I need however is a total of first contacts by day i.e.

```
First_Contact_Date… NoOfNewContacts  
01/01/2001……... ............    3  
02/01/2001…………........          1  
03/01/2001………............       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are half-way there.  You just need one more aggregation:

```
SELECT FirstContactDate, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT Customer , MIN(Visit) as FirstContactDate
      FROM T1
      GROUP BY cust
     ) t
GROUP BY FirstContactDate
ORDER BY FirstContactDate;
```

A note on data types:  `Visit` should be stored in the database using a `date` or related type.  This will ensure that the `order by` works correctly.  If you *have* to store a date as a string, then use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.  Then the `order by` will work correctly.